# SSL Error in Laravel while calling external API

Tags: laravel, ssl, curl

I am calling an External API through Laravel and facing "OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104".
Here is the complete logcat at the link below: 
https://www.overksa.com/wasl

Comment: are you getting or posting data?

Comment: I have tried both requests and its giving same error. And if I call any other api(sample api from internet). It generates result. Means the code is working good but gives error with this specific API. 
I cannot figure out if its error on Third Party API's side or my server

Comment: With SSL, make sure that you have an OpenSSL extension turned on from php.ini.